# Why Must I Put An Arrow Function Instead of Just the Return Value in React Event Handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, event-handling

I have looked over a bit of textbooks and blog posts but most seem just mumble through without a clear explanation...

in a event handler in React, I was told to write,

```
onChange = {() => setValue(someValue)}

onChange = {() => this.props.someFunction(someValue)}
```

I just don't understand why I cannot simply write something like

```
onChange = {setValue(someValue)}

onChange = {this.props.someFunction(someValue)}
```

since in my understanding setValue is a function by itself already, "() =>" look absolutely redundant to me.

On the other hand, if the event is defined within a class then I am allowed to write like this

```
onChange = {this.someFunction}
```

How come I am not required to write as aarow function in this case then? Like

```
onChange = {() => this.someFunction}
```

Isn't that double standard???

Comment: The second examples don't pass a function to be called by the change event. Instead it will immediate fire the function and pass the return value to the change event. That is probably not desired.

Comment: _"() => look absolutely redundant to me."_ - it's not. It has a purpose. You seem to be mixing up class component methods and functional component hooks as well.

Comment: i am certainly mixing up something or otherwise i won't be asking any questions here, don't you think???

Comment: You may thought they we're the same. It's good to help clarify these things.

Answer (score 3):

Because this:

```
this.someFunction
```

and this:

```
this.someFunction()
```

are two *very* different things.  The first one is a reference to the function *itself*, whereas the second one *executes* the function and evaluates to its return value.

So when you do this:

```
onChange = {this.someFunction}
```

you're telling it:

> When the value changes, execute `this.someFunction` and pass it the change event.

But when you do this:

```
onChange = {this.someFunction()}
```

you're telling it:

> Execute `this.someFunction` *right now*, passing it nothing.  When the value changes, execute whatever `this.someFunction` *returned* (which probably isn't an executable function) and pass it the change event.

The purpose of the arrow function is to create a function where one doesn't already exist.  So if you just have a simple function reference, pass it:

```
onChange = {this.someFunction}
```

But suppose you want to do two things, not just call that one function.  In that case you'd wrap those two things in an anonymous function:

```
onChange = {(e) => {
  this.someFunction(e);
  somethingElse();
}}
```

Or even simpler, suppose you have a simple function reference but it exepcts the new changed value instead of the change event itself:

```
onChange = {(e) => this.someFunction(e.target.event)}
```

Basically you create a function if you don't already have one which does what you want.

Comment: thanks! seem to get it now, its mainly about "referring to a function for later use" VS "immediately firing a function and returning nothing" i guess.

Comment: Useful to note also that if the function reference will receive a parameter and the calling code will send a matching argument, the function reference can be simplified from `onChange={val => someFunction(val)}` to `onChange={someFunction}` and it will have the same result.

Comment: @BoscoTsin: Basically, ya.  If it's a matter of being new to JavaScript, it's worth noting that JavaScript can pass around functions like any other object whereas many, many other languages either don't do that or do it only recently (and sometimes a bit weirdly).  As you get into asynchronous operations with promises and callbacks and such, you'll see a lot more functions being passed as arguments.  So you can essentially think of this in the same way, passing a "callback" to `onChange`.